# Can i commit to the origin/master branch locally?

Tags: git

i did this

```
git checkout origin/master
# made some changes
git commit -a -m "test something"
```

After this i did a `git checkout master`. Then i got this message

```
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  44af060 test something

If you want to keep it by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch <new-branch-name> 44af060

Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

My question is that why this commit does not belong to any branch. I made it on the origin/master head.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+origin%2Fmaster+Warning%3A+you+are+leaving+commit+behind

Comment: `origin/master` is not a normal branch. It's a special kind of reference called *remote-tracking branch*. And though it has "branch" in its name it's actually not. It's not supposed to be used as a branch. When you want to commit you're very much advised to create a normal local branch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to help.

When you init a repository you are in master/origin branch so if you created another branch you probably need to commit from that branch

You can also reference anywhere you've been by using the reflog:

```
git reflog
```

and after that you can that commit